# svn delete local edited-file on `update` instead of raising a Conflict

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN Client 1.12 with VisualSVN server (don't know version). 
Me and Jack (my colleague) and Daisy (my 2nd colleague) checkout a svn repo to locals,
There is a file called `ImageCutter.cs`. Revision is `951`
Jack delete it and `commit` changes to server (revision `952`)
Daisy update, edit something else, then commit to server (revision ...`989`)
I still update the `ImageCutter.cs` file.
I `update` (from root directory) and got my edited `ImageCutter.cs` gone, not even in `Recycle Bin`, **no Conflict raised**. 
How could this happened? 
I don't know much about svn but I think there should be a `conflict` raised when I `Update` and others guys deleted a file while I updated on my local. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I wrong?

Yes. `svn up` updates your WC to the state of (given) revision, conflict will be raised **only** both sides have overlapping changes, in all other cases repo-state have bigger priority (while nor-overlapping changes in repo in your WC will be merged)